# How to get names of scheduled queries in bigquery

Tags: python, api, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, bigdata

Using a python client to connect with bigquery, how can we get names of all the scheduled queries present in that project?

I tried following up with this link - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/datatransfer/libraries

But got no information on the names of the scheduled queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list all the scheduled queries for a project with `Python` `BigQuery` `Client` :

```py
def get_scheduled_queries_configs():
    from google.cloud import bigquery_datatransfer

    transfer_client = bigquery_datatransfer.DataTransferServiceClient()

    project_id = "{project_id}"
    parent = transfer_client.common_location_path(project=project_id, location='EU')

    request = bigquery_datatransfer.ListTransferConfigsRequest(
        parent=parent,
        data_source_ids=['scheduled_query']
    )

    configs = transfer_client.list_transfer_configs(request=request)
    print("Got the following configs:")
    for config in configs:
        print(f"\tID: {config.name}, Schedule: {config.schedule}")
        print(f"\tDisplay name: {config.display_name}")

        config_name = config.name
        config_schedule = config.schedule
        config_display_name = config.display_name

    return configs


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduled_queries_configs = get_scheduled_queries_configs()
```

Some explanations :

- This code retrieves `transfer configs` only for scheduled queries via `ListTransferConfigsRequest` object. The request takes the parent argument containing the project and the location `EU` in this example. The request take also `data_source_ids` argument with `scheduled_query` value
- The location is important because if your scheduled queries are in US and you execute the request in EU, the result will be empty
- The `config.display_name` allows to retrieve the name of a scheduled query

Comment: Why are two versions of bigquery_datatransfer used in the solution?

Comment: I changed it, and now I use the same import everywhere.